# Could someone please explain theses javascript concepts?

Tags: javascript, constructor

So I've been looking at [this code](http://codepen.io/akm2/pen/rHIsa) lately and I struggle understanding some things.

When the "class" is first declared with this following code, I understand :

```
function GravityPoint(x, y, radius, targets) {
    Vector.call(this, x, y);
    this.radius = radius;
    this.currentRadius = radius * 0.5;

    this._targets = {
        particles: targets.particles || [],
        gravities: targets.gravities || []
    };
    this._speed = new Vector();
}
```

Am I right saying that `Vector.call(this, x, y);` is used so you don't have to declare a position Vector ? If I understand right, you can then call :

```
var a = new GravityPoint(0,0,10,[..]);
```

and then `a.x == 0` ? (assuming Vector has x and y properties)

My second question is about this piece of code :

```
GravityPoint.prototype = (function(o) {
    var s = new Vector(0, 0), p;
    for (p in o) s[p] = o[p];
    return s;
})({
    gravity:       0.05,
    isMouseOver:   false,
    dragging:      false,
    destroyed:     false,
    _easeRadius:   0,
    _dragDistance: null,
    _collapsing:   false,

    hitTest: function(p) {
        return this.distanceTo(p) < this.radius;
    }
    ...
});
```

I don't understand this structure : `MyClass.prototype = (function(o){})({ prop1:val1})`

For me, it's like sending the second part (`{ prop1:val1}`) as an argument to the function `function(o){}` which doesn't make sense since this function return a vector.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [prototyping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) typical of JS in order to better understand this comment. Basically `GravityPoint` "inherits" from `Vector`. This is done by setting the prototype of `GravityPoint` to and object of type `Vector`, so that if a method/field is accessed on the former, it is eventually searched in the latter if not redefined. This is what `return s` do. The for simply copies the properties of the argument into the `Vector` used as a prototype. This gives them a default value.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explaination !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [immediately-invoked function expressions or iffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

simple example

```
(function(a, b) {
  // a == 'hello'
  // b == 'world'
})('hello', 'world');
```

in your case you are defining this iffy function

```
function(o) {
    var s = new Vector(0, 0), p;
    for (p in o) s[p] = o[p];
    return s;
}
```

then invoking it with this argument and storing the result in GravityPoint.prototype.

```
{
    gravity:       0.05,
    isMouseOver:   false,
    dragging:      false,
    destroyed:     false,
    _easeRadius:   0,
    _dragDistance: null,
    _collapsing:   false,

    hitTest: function(p) {
        return this.distanceTo(p) < this.radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and why is Vector.call() used in the GravityPoint constructor ? It has to do with the prototype inheritance ?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent to calling super(this); in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification !